# how to sort multiarray with the sub value

Tags: php, arrays, php-5.3

i have multidimensional array with Unexpected numbers of product groups

i want to sort all these groups by the lowest count number for all these groups

***as example*** : the first group after resort will be the input product group because it has the lowest count number and then  the input product group ..etc

how to do this?

```
<?php
$a = 
// the output product group
array(
        array('id' => 117, 'name' => 'monitor', 'count' => 60),
        array('id' => 118, 'name' => 'printer', 'count' => 16),
        array('id' => 119, 'name' => 'sound card', 'count' => 19),
// the input product group
  array(
        array('id' => 120, 'name' => 'keyboard', 'count' => 11),
        array('id' => 121, 'name' => 'hard', 'count' => 21),
        array('id' => 122, 'name' => 'mouse', 'count' => 24)
      )
    )

;       
// this code does't works good
// Obtain a list of columns
foreach ($a as $key => $row) {
    $count[$key]  = $row['count'];
}
// Sort the data with mid descending
// Add $data as the last parameter, to sort by the common key
 array_multisort($count, SORT_ASC, $a);

 echo $count[$key];
?>
```

Comment: can you merge the groups and then do the sort?

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused by the structure of $a. The products 120-122 are inside an array that is sibling to the products 117-119. Surely there should be another array wrapping the "group" of 117-119? I'm going to assume that's what was intended, otherwise it makes no sense. So that should be:

```
$a = array(
    array(
        array('id' => 117, 'name' => 'monitor', 'count' => 60),
        array('id' => 118, 'name' => 'printer', 'count' => 16),
        array('id' => 119, 'name' => 'sound card', 'count' => 19),
    ),
    array(
        array('id' => 120, 'name' => 'keyboard', 'count' => 11),
        array('id' => 121, 'name' => 'hard', 'count' => 21),
        array('id' => 122, 'name' => 'mouse', 'count' => 24),
    ),
);
```

Now if I understand correctly, you want to sort the groups according to the lowest count of any product inside the group. You can do that with a custom sort function like so:

```
// first calculate the lowest count for each group
foreach ($a as $key => $group) {
    $lowestCount = null;
    foreach ($group as $product) {
        if ($lowestCount === null || $lowestCount > $product['count']) {
            $lowestCount = $product['count'];
        }
    }
    $a[$key]['lowestCount'] = $lowestCount;
}

// sort groups according to their lowest count
usort($a, function($group1, $group2) {
    return $group1['lowestCount'] - $group2['lowestCount'];
});

// clean up the 'lowestCount' variables
foreach ($a as $key => $group) unset($a[$key]['lowestCount']);
```

The output will contain the group of 120-122 first, then the group of 117-119, because 11 is less than 16. If that's not what you wanted, please clarify!

Edit: For old PHP (5.2 and below), change the sort code to:

```
// sort groups according to their lowest count
if (!function_exists('groupSort')) {
    function groupSort($group1, $group2) {
        return $group1['lowestCount'] - $group2['lowestCount'];
    }
}
usort($a, 'groupSort');
```

Comment: I SEE THIS MESSAGE LANGUAGE FEATURE NOT COMPATIBLE WITH PHP VERSION INDICATED IN PROJECT SETTINGS SO WHAT?

Comment: @user1673473 That's strange. Anonymous functions were added in PHP 5.3. In your question you tagged PHP 5.3. If you can change the project settings, set the PHP version to PHP 5.3. If not, use the alternate lines I added above.